# Touchpad breaks on resume - Why doesn't synclient work in shell script?

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, synaptics

Sometimes suspend-resume breaks the use of the trackpad on XPS 15. I made a quick shell script to fix it again:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
synclient TapButton3=2
synclient FingerHigh=40
synclient FingerLow=35
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
```

While it makes the touchpad work again, it doesn't do the synclient adjustments to make the middle button a three-finger-click, and adjust the tapping presssure so it doesn't move when tapping. (I have these 4 in a command in "startup applications", with ; separating them, and that does work)

Why does synclient not work from shell script, but running those commands immediately after, does work?

Answer (score 0):

Is the script running from within an X server? If not you need to set the `DISPLAY` variable

Is the hardware still initialising? You could try adding a sleep after the `modprobe` to make sure it is fully working before the rest of the commands run. (This probably isn't the case as the kernel should fully initialise the device before handing it back to usersspace)

Is the `modprobe` command working? Try adding `--first-time` so that it reports if it's already loaded, also try replacing `rmmod` with `modprobe -r` (for your use `rmmod` should work but `modprobe -r` is the recommended tool)

Sorry these are mostly questions but I don't have enough kudos to add a comment

Comment: Modprobe is working, or else the touchpad wouldn't work again. I'm running the script by Ctrl+Alt+T, running `./fixtouchpad.sh`.

Comment: modprobe will fail silently if the module is already loaded, rmmod should through an error when removing though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run your script every time you "plug in your touchpad" - which includes resuming from suspend. To do that you should point to your script from the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices.hotplug-command` configuration key. You could do that through `dconf-editor` for example, or by running the following command (once) from the shell (replace the text within the double quotes with the right path):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/input-devices/hotplug-command "/absolute/path/to/your/script"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but I think the original problem here is nonexistent in 14.04

Comment: @NoBugs: well, I've had the same problem (at least with the `synclient` settings) on 14.10.